# How can I debug a tool that is installed by pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pip, pdb

I have a tool installed by the command pip install.

However, I would like to use a debugger to go through its execution flow.

I know for debugging what usually happens is attach pdb in command line.
like
`python3 -m pdb [some args]`

But the tool is working like this
`tool [some args]`

How can attach a debugger to this?

Comment: on linux you could use `which tool` to get `/full/path/tool` and then you could open it in text editor and add code for debuging. And if it is Python code then you can always run as `python3 /full/path/tool` and then you can add `-m pdb`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux in console/terminal you can use

```
which tool
```

to get `/full/path/to/tool`

and then you can run

```
python3 -m pdb /full/path/to/tool [some args]
```

You can also use `/full/path/to/tool` to open it in text editor and see source code, and add some code for debuging.

---

On Windows should be similar function to find full path to `tool` and then you can do the same.

---

If you can `import tool` in Python then you can also use `print( tool.__file__` ) to get `/full/path/to/tool`